# Unable to pipe template class to cout

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, ostream, c++98

When I try to compile the following (truncated into the small snippet below) code,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename value_type>
class Tree {
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
};

template <typename value_type>
const std::ostream& operator<<(const std::ostream& o, const Tree<value_type>& t) {
    return o;
}

int main() {
    Tree<int> tree;
    cout << tree << endl;
}
```

I get the following errors:

**clang** on a mac

```
error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved;
      did you mean to call it?
        cout << tree << endl;
                        ^~~~
```

**gnu gcc** on debian linux

```
error: no match for 'operator<<'
(operand types are
    'const ostream {aka const std::basic_ostream<char>}'
    and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')
        cout << tree << endl;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

If I never implement the operator overload, gnu g++ instead gives me the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<'
(operand types are
    'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}'
    and 'Tree<int>')
        cout << tree << endl;
        ~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

I don't actually understand what I am doing wrong here. All I want to do is be able to pipe my template class to `ostream` as you do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `const`s on `std::ostream` - you can't use a const stream for anything.

```
template <typename value_type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Tree<value_type>& t) {
    return o;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I've done this in the past and it has worked fine and yet now my compilers are choosing to only accept non-constants..

Comment: @finnrayment You may have done that with other operators, but I doubt that any compiler has ever been broken enough to let you do it with `operator<<` and `std::ostream`. (Note that you won't get a problem if you never use the stream - `std::cout << tree;` should work as long as your overload doesn't write anything.)

Comment: Honest to god, I swear I did it with `operator<<` on `std::ostream` the other day and it compiled on more than three computers... Regardless, you have solved my issue, so thank you very much!

Comment: @finnrayment it is "fine" for `std::cout << x;` but anything beyond that not. The stream itself it not const of course, but `std::cout << x;` results in a `const` reference, hence `std::cout << x << whatever;` cannot work

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Ah-hah ! That would be why; I was doing one liners exactly like that

Comment: @finnrayment I fall into this trap on a regular basis, forgetting to return the stream, ignoring the warning, all seems fine until I use chaining...